# Custom Cell UICollectionView in Swift

Tags: ios, swift

I am trying to create different cells for each index item in my collectionView and I am attempting to downcast them as their respective cell in order to access their variables.
The code below outputs this error "**Cannot assign value of type 'LiveCell.Type' to type 'UICollectionViewCell'**"

```
func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, cellForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UICollectionViewCell {
    let identifier: String
    let cellName: UICollectionViewCell

    if indexPath.item == 1 {
        identifier = LiveCellId
        cellName = LiveCell
    } else if indexPath.item == 2 {
        identifier = LiveCellId
        cellName = LiveCell
    } else {
        identifier = FeedCellId
        cellName = FeedCell
    }

    let cell = collectionView.dequeueReusableCell(withReuseIdentifier: identifier, for: indexPath) as! cellName //Trying to downcast cell from the variable called cellName
    cell.homeController = self

    return cell
}
```

Is there a solution for this. Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do something like this:

```
func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, cellForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UICollectionViewCell {
    let identifier: String


    if indexPath.item == 1 || indexPath.item == 2 {
        identifier = LiveCellId
        let cell = collectionView.dequeueReusableCell(withReuseIdentifier: identifier, for: indexPath) as! LiveCell 
        cell.homeController = self
        return cell

    } else {

        identifier = FeedCellId
        let cell = collectionView.dequeueReusableCell(withReuseIdentifier: identifier, for: indexPath) as! FeedCell
        cell.homeController = self 
        return cell
    }


}
```

Comment: Works great. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Try This:-

```
func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, cellForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UICollectionViewCell {
    let identifier: String
    let cellName: UICollectionViewCell?

    if indexPath.item == 1 {
        identifier = LiveCellId 
        cellName = LiveCell as? UICollectionViewCell
    } else if indexPath.item == 2 {
        identifier = LiveCellId
        cellName = LiveCell as? UICollectionViewCell
    } else {
        identifier = FeedCellId
        cellName = FeedCell as? UICollectionViewCell
    }

    let cell = collectionView.dequeueReusableCell(withReuseIdentifier: identifier, for: indexPath) as! cellName //Trying to downcast cell from the variable called cellName
    cell.homeController = self

    return cell
}
```

Comment: looked like it would however it gives me "Cast from 'FeedCell.Type' to unrelated type 'UICollectionViewCell' always fails"